# Given a list of numbers, how can I remove all multiples of primes (but not primes)?

Tags: python

I am starting on my Python journey and am doing some exercises to get the hang of it all. One question is really giving me troubles as I do not understand how to complete it.

Question:
Given a list of natural numbers, remove from it all multiples of 2 (but not 2), multiples of 3 (but not 3), and so on, up to the multiples of 100, and print the remaining values.

From this question I take it that I should first make a list with all prime numbers and after that append the values that correspond to a new list. This is what I have until know:

```
# Read list:
a = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# First get a list with all primes
primes = []
for i in range(0, 101):
    for j in range(2, int(i ** 0.5) + 1):
         if i%j == 0:
             break
    else:
        primes.append(i)

# Next append to new list
b = []
for num in a:
    for prime in primes:
        if num == prime and num % prime == 0:
            b.append(num)  
print(b)
```

Now this works for this simple example, but upon testing it on another set (one of which I do not know the input values of the test case), my output is:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Which is my original list with the prime numbers. So somewhere along the line I am making a mistake and I cannot see the logic behind it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you remove multiples of primes, wouldn't you be left with primes?

Comment: @NeoMent I am not filtering out the prime number but using those to see which correspond with the given list.

Comment: @enke yes of course, the only thing is I do not know what the test case input list is, so cannot check whether the right output is the list of all primes from 0-100

Comment: Try using a generator:
for i in range(2,101):
    a = [j for j in a if (j==i or j%i!=0)]

Comment: I would think the test is numbers 2-100 since your output is primes up to 100

Comment: It's not clear to me what your expected output is. Your algorithm sounds like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and getting a list of primes is the entire point.

Comment: A multiple of a prime is, by definition, not prime. Therefore if you have a list of natural numbers from which you remove all multiples of primes you'll be left with all prime numbers

Comment: @MisterMiyagi sorry that I cannot be any clearer. The initial test list, the [5, 6, 7, 8, 9} runs perfectly but then there is a test case with an unknown input list that does not give the correct result when plugged in. Maybe it's a fault of the system but I think there is something else.

Comment: @NeoMent, your generator seems to do the trick! Amazing thank you! Now I just need to find out what I did wrong. Do you want to add the correct answer?

Comment: Can you clarify "up to the multiples of 100". For example, if your list of numbers contained 17869 (which has the factors 107 and 167 and thus not prime) are you saying that it should remain in the list - i.e., because its lowest factor is >100 ?

Comment: @OlvinRoght That is a very good question. I believe that that would indeed be the case but this example is probably outside the scope of the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the task all you need to do is filter out the numbers by using a generator and a for loop, which by itself is already finding the prime numbers

```
a = [5,6,7,8,9]
for i in range(2,101):
    a = [j for j in a if (j==i or j%i!=0)]
```